# mongoose behaviour when saving updated ref fields

Tags: mongoose

I would appreciate some insight on mongoose's behaviour when changing ref values in a populated (or unpopulated) model.

Assuming we have:

```
var CountrySchema = new Schema({
  _capital: { type: ObjectId, ref: City }
});

Country.findOne({}).populate('_capital').exec((err, country) => {
  /* CODE HERE */
  country.save((err, done);
});
```

If I put

```
country._capital = { name: 'Paris'};
```

this will

- result in a CastError if _capital was not set yet. (Operator overloading in JS, WTF?)
- result in a CastError likewise, if _capital is set but the model *isn't* populated.
- work if _capital is set and the model is populated. The referenced city item will be replaced by the new Paris one. The referenced ObjectId (_capital) is changed and the old city document is removed from the City collection.

All of this wasn't obsious to me and I'm still wondering what happens e.g. when

- assigning ids instead of objects to a populated ref field.
- extending a populated ref array with objects/ids.
- removing ref values from a populated model.

Is it systematic? Is this the wrong way of doing things? Is it in the docs?

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html 404s currently.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/populate.html doesn't help much.

Before I go about testing myself I was wondering if you guys could help me out with this.

One more question: I'm currently using 4.5.2. Is there some sort of recommended LTS version?

Thanks!

M